# Add new item to the solution programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I have a package extension of VS2013 version which has tool window and few controls in it. I would like to import few entries as a class file to the current project. Basically, I would like to add new item to current project using an extension.

Could somebody help out with this one?

Comment: Add new item, like any other vs project...

Comment: Do you mean programmatically add new items to a project when you click a button on your tool window?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can get the EnvDTE.Project from the IVsHierarchy](https://mhusseini.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/convert-ivshierarchy-to-projectitem-or-project/)

Then, given an EnvDTE.Project, you can use [EnvDTE.Project.ProjectItems.AddFromFile, AddFromFileCopy, etc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.aspx).