# Create item from Item Template programmatically in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vssdk

I am developing a [VS extension called WebLink](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lostmsu.WebLink), that replaces integrated VS browser.

I'd like to create a command, which would do the following, if a solution is loaded:

1. If current solution does not have a folder named "Links" at the top level, create it.
2. Create a new file in that folder, using an Item Template I ship with my extension, named `new tab XX.website` (the file should be placed in SolutionDir\Links\ )
3. Open that file in the document well

My problem is with 2: how do I get VS to create a new file, and use the specified item template for it?

Comment: What's the specific reason that you want to create the file before creating the Item? In normal situation, I think we [add the Item Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098057/add-new-item-to-the-solution-programmatically) in solution folder with custom name, and move it to links folder with code in that command...

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT the order does not matter as long as the result is the same: a file exists created from my template, it is physically and logically in Links folder, and it is opened in the document well.

Comment: Hi friend, sorry for the delay. Any update for this issue? Can the link in my comment helps to resolve this issue. I guess your actual issue is more complex than what you described in question, if the issue persists, please share more details about what you tried and where you're blocked so that I can research it deeply :)